# What are the consequences of a player race not being humanoid?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits

Part of the reason I'm asking this is because the UA centuar  and minotaur both have a feature that says the type is *both* humanoid and monstrosity. This implies that having a non-humanoid race would not be balanced. But it seems that if the type was something like elemental it would be balanced due to the fact you could be bound using spells like *planar binding* and that this would offset the boost the spells such as *hold person* wouldn't work on you.
So would such a race be balanced?

Comment: Please let us know if that question doesn't answer yours. If there's a missing piece, please include it in your question and we can get it reopened.

Comment: I'm starting to doubt my duplication...but if you're asking a specific build, we'd need to know the specific build in order to determine balance.

Comment: @NautArch: I don't think it's exactly a duplicate, because many of the answers to the related question address the specific fact that the centaur is fey, not just non-humanoid. But I do think the asker here isn't even aware that the centaur is fey, and it's not exactly clear what problem they're trying to solve - so it might be better to get more information and refine the question before reopening it.